# History tracking field

Tags: history-tracking, field-history

I need to create a field with history tracking of on pages where the users assigned to a particular record needs to be tracked from the field.

I tried below steps but they are not working for me. To track field history for custom objects:

From Setup, click Create | Objects.

Click Edit next to the name of the custom object.

Select the Track Field History checkbox.

Click Save.

i am completely new to this. can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1):

After you enable that there are two more steps that you need to do.

1) Click on name of the object -> From Custom Fields and Related List Area Click on the button called Set history Tracking . Now select all the values fro here that you want to track and click save.

2) Now customise your page layout to include Object's History related list.

Comment: its already done. the page is designed (by other team) as generic so that all the fields selected for history tracking will appear in it. but if i try to add a new field that is not visible in history.